# Adding a trailing slash at the end of the URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

im trying to redirect the url without trailing slash to slash at the end but having some problem..im able to redirect but getting index.php in the url like http://www.domain.com/subdomain/index.php/url/... so how do i strip the index.php again?...my code is below..any help would be appreciated..thanks in advance!!

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[^./]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/subdomain/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That's your complete `.htaccess`?